# Глобально отслеживать нажатия клавиш

Tags: c#, события

Как глобально (не в рамках моего приложения) отследить нажимаемые комбинации клавиш и, если, к примеру, комбинация CTRL+Q то активировать мое приложение? Перенести фокус то бишь. Ну или на какой-либо элемент в нем. TextBox, например.
Спасибо!

Comment: [GetAsyncKeyState][1]

[Control.ModifierKey][2]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(VS.85).aspx
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys.aspx

Comment: [Set global hotkeys using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp)

Comment: мне нужно ГЛОБАЛЬНО. то есть я, скажем, работаю в браузере и хочу а) активировать (б)включить) свое приложение посредством комбинации клавиш ALT+F1 к примеру

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите сюда: [MSDN/Hooks overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Учтите, что с такими трюками ваше приложение не получит Vista Logo (и более поздние сертификации): благопристойной программе не к чему шпионить за другими программами.

Comment: в принципе согшласен. ну а если это муз проигрыватель то это теперь неблагопристойная программа?)

Comment: любая программа, делающая неблагопристойные вещи, наблагопристойна сама :)

Comment: Что-то ссылка не сильно живая :(

Comment: @Qwertiy: Оживил :)

Comment: Хм.. Тоже хуки... А почему никто не предложил просто RegisterHotkey сделать?

Comment: @Qwertiy: ПишЫ ответ :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Или можно задубликатить к этому: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779662/10105

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать такую подтехнологию WinAPI, как хуки( HOOKS ). Вообще, внедрение низкого уровня в C# - дело не клевое, так как .NET предоставляет массу высокоуровневых( и наиболее удобных, кстати говоря ) замещений WinAPI функциям. Но, если б я столкнулся с вашей задачей, вероятно, я бы решил ее именно так:

```
HOOKPROC hkprcSysMsg;
static HINSTANCE hinstDLL; 
static HHOOK hhookSysMsg;

hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("c:\\myapp\\MyHookDLL.dll")); 
hkprcSysMsg = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "MyHookProc");

hhookSysMsg = SetWindowsHookEx( 
                    WH_KEYBOARD,
                    hkprcSysMsg,
                    hinstDLL,
                    0);
```

**[Доки.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx)**
При этом нажатия клавиш( и их комбинаций ) будет перехвачено глобально, на уровне системы, созданным вами хуком.

Comment: а почему не использовать атрибут DLLImport? С ним же красивее.

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло: А это и есть с `DllImport`, по-другому вы `SetWindowsHookEx` не вызовете.

Comment: Снимаю вопрос и извиняюсь, я подумал что это такой хитрый способ вызова ф-ии из другой длл, потом просмотрел доки на SetWindowsHookEx и как она работает и зачем ей делать LoadLibrary.

Comment: Зачем выносить функционал хука в отдельную DLL? В двух словах, затем, чтобы памяти у функции-хука было больше. Хуки достаточно ресурсоемки.

Comment: эм.. я в хуках не очень разбираюсь.. как конкретно мне следует применить этот код?

Answer (score 0):

> EasyHook starts where Microsoft Detours ends.
> This project supports extending (hooking) unmanaged code (APIs) with pure managed ones, from within a fully managed environment like C# using Windows 2000 SP4 and later, including Windows XP x64, Windows Vista x64 and Windows Server 2008 x64. Also 32- and 64-bit kernel mode hooking is supported as well as an unmanaged user-mode API which allows you to hook targets without requiring a NET Framework on the customers PC. An experimental stealth injection hides hooking from most of the current AV software.

http://easyhook.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите в сторону winapi, в шарпе нет возможности взаимодействовать напрямую с неподготовленными приложениями.