# Как отловить нажатие клавиш в WPF-приложении, когда оно свёрнуто?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, clickonce, keyboardhook

Имеется **WPF**-приложение (аудио-проигрыватель). Необходимо добавить возможность отлавливать нажатие определённых клавиш, даже когда приложение свёрнуто. Например, при нажатии *Num4* - останавливать вопроизведение, при нажатии других клавиш (в зависимости от настроек - продолжать воспроизведение музыки и т.п.). 
Пробовал реализовать через функцию `GetAsyncKeyState(int vkey)` из `user32.dll`, но мне это не совсем подходит, вот пример кода:

```
public static class KeyState
{
    public static void Wait(Key key, Action<KeyStates> action)
    {
        var asyncOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
        SendOrPostCallback callBack = state => action((KeyStates) state);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            var vk = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(key);                
            var prev = ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk) & 0x8000) == 0x8000);
            if (prev)
            {
                asyncOperation.Post(callBack, KeyStates.Down);
            }
            while (true)
            {
                var res = ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk) & 0x8000) == 0x8000);
                if (res != prev && res)
                {
                    asyncOperation.Post(callBack, KeyStates.Down);
                }
                prev = res;
            }
        });
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vkey);
}
```

Проблема здесь в том, что мне не только нужно **отловить** нажатие клавиши, но и п**редотвратить "продвижение"** нажатия клавиши далее. Т.е. нажатие клавиши должно перехватываться моим приложением и не попадать в другие (например, в текстовый редактор).
Буду благодарен за помощь. Если кто-нибудь ещё и подскажет как это корректно реализовать для приложения, которое развертывается через *ClickOnce*, было бы вообще шикарно. Спасибо!

Comment: Это вам глобальный хук нужен. Проще всего, наверное, через WinAPI.

Comment: А можно поподробнее?

Comment: Ну например: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Windows Vista можно использовать функцию [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx). Она позволяет зарегистрировать глобальную горячую клавишу и указать окно, которое будет принимать сообщения. Чтобы обработать эти сообщения в WPF приложении, нужно зарегистрировать обработчик через [HwndSource.AddHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.addhook(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример как обработать событие горячей клавиши и вывести момент ее нажатия в TextBlock:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WpfHotkey
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        //необходимые константы
        public const int MOD_ALT = 0x1;
        public const int MOD_CONTROL = 0x2;
        public const int MOD_SHIFT = 0x4;
        public const int MOD_WIN = 0x8;
        public const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;

        //несколько примеров виртуальных кодов
        public const uint VK_F1 = 0x70;
        public const uint VK_F2 = 0x71;
        public const uint VK_UP = 0x26;
        public const uint VK_DOWN = 0x28;

        //обработчик сообщений для окна
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {

            if (msg == WM_HOTKEY)
            {
                textBlock1.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString() + " WM_HOTKEY message, ID: 0x" + wParam.ToString("X");
                textBlock1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                handled = true;
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));//регистрируем обработчик сообщений

            bool res = RegisterHotKey(h.Handle, 1, 0, VK_F1);//регистрируем горячую клавишу
            if (res == false) MessageBox.Show("RegisterHotKey failed");
        }
    }
}
```