# C# Активация по нажатию клавиши на клавиатуре при свернутой форме

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как я могу продолжить работу программы по нажатию, к примеру, F12? Форма в этот момент свернута.

Comment: Вижу такой вариант. 1. Переназначить значение клавиши F12. При ее нажатии записывать какое-нибудь значение в реестр или xml. Ваша программа должна быть многопоточной. В одном из потоков считывается значение из реестра (xml) через опр. время. Это как вариант

Comment: @АлександрПузанов пример бы "записи значения в реестр"

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764352/Как-отловить-нажатие-клавиш-в-wpf-приложении-когда-оно-свёрнуто/779662#779662

Comment: В гугле можно найти много примеров. Дам лишь совет... записывайте в ветку HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<Имя_вашей_программы>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Низкоуровневый перехват клавиш к Вашим услугам!) Ключ `F12` - `123`.

Для нахождения ключей других клавиш, можете раскомментировать строку с `mBox`'ом.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Whooper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;


        private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback;
        private IntPtr m_hHook;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(
            int idHook,
            LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn,
            IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);


        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(IntPtr lpModuleName);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(
            IntPtr hhk,
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                var khs = (KeyboardHookStruct)
                          Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam,
                          typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));
                if (Convert.ToInt32("" + wParam) == 256)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(khs.VirtualKeyCode+""); //Показать Ключ нажатой клавиши
                    if ((int)khs.VirtualKeyCode==123)//123 - F12
                    {
                        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    }
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct KeyboardHookStruct
        {
            public readonly int VirtualKeyCode;
            public readonly int ScanCode;
            public readonly int Flags;
            public readonly int Time;
            public readonly IntPtr ExtraInfo;
        }


        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


        public void SetHook()
        {
            m_callback = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc;
            m_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                m_callback,
                GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        }

        public void Unhook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetHook();
        }
    }
}
```

Взял из своего рабочего проекта. Если у Вас будут какие-то вопросы - решим их.

Comment: Большое спасибо, странно только, что для такого вроде бы простого действия нужны такие костыли)

Comment: @Stepan начиная с Висты, не нужны. Функция RegisterHotKey