# Как сделать что бы программа свёрнутая в трей выводила сообщение

Tags: c#, winforms, клавиатура

Мне нужно что бы программа могла выводить сообщение (и не только) даже когда свёрнута.(Выводит только когда открыта и активна форма)
Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Vm
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Ok");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: вам нужно что-бы по нажатию некой клавиши у вас выскакивало сообщение, правильно я понял?

Comment: Да,так и получается,но когда она скрыта,сообщение не выводится,а мне нужно что бы оно выводилось

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764352/Как-отловить-нажатие-клавиш-в-wpf-приложении-когда-оно-свёрнуто?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Это на wpf а у меня winforms

Comment: используйте [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx)